# VSTO(.vb) uses EXCEL built-in function Match() exception

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

Project is VSTO Excel Add-in (vb), when using EXCEL built-in function Match(), an exception occurs.

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Function match_out ()
    Dim index As Integer

    'The build error is here
    index= excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, {2, 1})
    
    return index
End Function
```

I want output result:

```
index = 2
```

but feedback:

```
error:BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Application` property of your VSTO add-in class (`ThisAddin`) to call a worksheet function:

```
index= Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, {2, 1})
```

`excel` is just an alias to the namespace imported.

See [Application.WorksheetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.worksheetfunction) property which returns the [WorksheetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) object.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your advice.   So can `Application.WorksheetFunction` only be used in `Excel -> ThisAddIn.vb`??   

Can't use inside a new homebrew Class.vb?

Comment: You can use the static class and its properties that allows to access the host `Application` class. `Globals` is a static class that keeps references to certain items in your project. By using the `Globals` class you can access the add-in object by using the `Globals.ThisAddIn` property.